# How to outline the div tag?

Tags: html, css

I try to outline the div tag. I used `border:0.01em solid black` but it is not correctly fit.
My script below

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="color" style="width:100%; height:500px; background:gray;">
<div style="width:50%; height:500px; background:yellow;  float:left;"></div>
<div style="width:50%; height:500px; background:blue; float:left;">    </div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:500px; background:gray;">
<div style="width:50%; height:500px; border:0.01em solid black;  float:left;"></div>
<div style="width:50%; height:500px; border:0.01em solid black; float:left;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

That equal sepration of the `div id = color` tag is fit into the 100% width.

But equal sepration of the `div id = border` tag is not fit into the 100% 
because i added the `border` to seprate `div` tags, so size is increase like 50% + 0.01em.

That the reason `div id = border` tag's sub div tag is not fit into the 100%, so the second sub div tag is fall in down from 100%.

So i want to outline
the div tag not to border it? How can i do it? But i want to seprate by the 50% i not decrese it.

Comment: If you give border then it will take additionally and not from 50% given hence div will fall down.

Comment: @MihirBhatt Hmm ok. That the reason i need to outline the div tag?

Comment: If you want to give border then you need to decrease from those 50%.

Comment: @MihirBhatt I can't decrease my div tag width. Any other option for achieve it.?

Comment: Take one div with border inside each of div of having 50% width.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 box-sizing property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195707/css3-box-sizing-property)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under the standard box-model padding and borders are **added** to any defined width.

If you set the box-sizing to `border-box` then the declared width will **include** any padding & borders.

It's often seen as part of a Universal Selector:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:500px; background:gray;">
  <div style="width:50%; height:500px; border:1px solid black;  float:left;"></div>
  <div style="width:50%; height:500px; border:1px solid black; float:left;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is actually the purpose of the `outline` property:

```
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:500px; background:gray;">
    <div style="width:50%; height:500px; outline:0.01em solid black; float:left;"></div>
    <div style="width:50%; height:500px; outline:0.01em solid black; float:left;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Clean and simple.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below code:

```
<div id="color" style="width:100%; height:500px; background:gray;border:medium solid">
<div style="border-right: medium solid;  float:left;width:50%; height:500px;"></div>
```

This should work with your case.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
<div style="border-style: solid;border-width: medium;  float:left;width:50%; height:500px;"></div>
```

Comment: can you check you answer? These also give same result

Comment: @BlueLeaf I want to two sub div tag with 50% width into the 100% div.

Comment: @BlueLeaf If both div are of 50% then it will not fit adjacent.

Comment: Ya i checked it. `<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:500px; background:gray;">
<div style="border-style: solid; border-width: medium;  float:left; width:50%; height:500px;"></div>
<div style="border-style: solid; border-width: medium;  float:left; width:50%; height:500px;"></div>
</div>` this is not work

Comment: yeah, you have to define the two divs at 49%, or make one 50 and the second 48%.
you can also use bootstrap and divide them equally